# What message/instruction should be given for downloading an image for browser and/or tablet

Tags: image, messages, download

I need users to download an image from my web app. For browsers that support the HTML 5 'download' attribute my Download button automatically opens the browser download window. However, users on the remaining browsers need to download the image the old fashioned way.

To save an image from a browser on a non-touch device, one right clicks and selects "Save Image As..." and on a touch device, one can usually tap and hold the image and select the save image option.

What concise message/instruction will tell the user to perform the above mentioned actions to download the image? Since we cannot tell with 100% accuracy what device a user is using we would need a combined message (handling touch and non-touch devices)? Though seems that might be unwieldy and long.

Also is asking user's to "right click" on OSX valid? While there are a number of ways to right click, for the average OSX user, is it something one can expect knowledge of?

Comment: You can use `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` HTTP header to force most browsers to download it.

Comment: Force download using HTTP header `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`. You should also make the URL end with filename and extension. Example implementation in node.js (Express framework)
-----------------------------------------------------
Serves images stored in directory `./images/` named `photo-<number>.jpg`. Serves them on the same path (`http://127.1/images/photo-42.jpg`). ```js
const express = require('express')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path') const app = express() const imageDir = path.resolve(__dirname, "images") app.get('/image/:filename', (req, res, next) =

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yesterday I asked the question [Is a right-click equal to a long press?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/82157/is-a-right-click-equal-to-a-long-press) and got the answer that it is. So I would have the following message:

> Right-Click (or long press) the image to download it

All experienced Desktop users knows how to right-click independently of which operating system that is in place. The long press on the other hand is difficult to handle - but if you place the message of the long press - you'll give the users a clue what to do.

Comment: Do you think long press will clash with system context menu? For example, if you do a long press on iOS, it brings up the default editing menu. If the developer overwrites it with his own commands, it might confuse the user.

Comment: @AditGupta Or the developer can add an option if there is a default context menu already.

Comment: True. It can work in this case.  Although,  I do see a problem if you've more  self defined contextual commands than the generic ones.  Perhaps,  in that case,  a context menu will not work as intended.  What do you think?

Comment: @AditGupta It's hard to tell without proper testing. But I'm positive it would work without interfering with the users conceptual expectation of a long press. There could be a problem if you add too many options in the context meny. Better to keep it clean and just add one if necessary - as in this case.

Comment: Excellent. In this particular case, on iOS the long press on an image in the browser (Safari) brings up a menu with "Save Image" and "Copy", which suits my needs.